# jquery how to add onclick extra function while onclick original function buried in unknown js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

A bootstrap4 site, a gallery which includes two divs, one includes buttons, the other includes photos. Clicking some button will result in showing of photos with some tag kind. This filtering function is buried in some js file, I guess, and I don't want to touch that. Is it possible to just add extra function to button clicking? I want to add ID/anchor to photos div, and then when button clicked, make it scroll down to photos area. Will new onclick function overwrite orginal one?

Comment: No, you can add as many event handlers for any event as you want.  Provided you use the native `addEventListener` or the jQuery `on()` method of adding event listeners.

Comment: @Taplar Thank you, sir.  How do I accept a comment as correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the element and then add the event listener

```
element.addEventListener('click', handler);
```

instead of

```
element.onclick = handler;
```

MDN Link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener